# Defining multiple variables inside one

Tags: python, variables

Sorry I am new to python and I think I have seen someone, somewhere do something that resembled the following:

```
hiddenLayerinput = {
    units=64, 
    activation='relu', 
    input_dim=5
}
```

There is a syntax error at the = of units=64,
Can I do that? And if yes, do you know whats wrong?

Thank you for any help

I am using Jupyter notebooks running python 3

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a dictionary. You fill it with key-value-pairs like this `hiddenLayerinput = {'unit':64, 'activiation':'relu', 'input':5}`. Afterwards, you can access it like this: `hiddenLayerinput['unit']` to get `64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case hiddenLayerinput is a dictionary,
you can use it as :

```
hiddenLayerinput = {
"units" : 64,
"activation": "relu"
"input_dim": 5
}
```

Then you can acces it as : `hiddenLayerinput["units"]` , and you will get value of "units" : 64

Answer (score 1):

Python's dictionaries use `{}` and hence

```
hiddenLayerinput = {
    units=64, 
    activation='relu', 
    input_dim=5
}
```

is identified as a dictionary, `=` is `SyntaxError` you get. You need to change all the `=`s to `:`s

```
hiddenLayerinput = {
    "units":64, 
    "activation":'relu', 
    "input_dim":5
}
```

**Edit** - `units`, `activation`, `input_dim` are keys. If you have `units`, `activation`, `input_dim` as variables, you can remove the quotes and the values from those variables will be used as keys.
Read more about [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: You probably want to use string literals as keys here - it is technically legal to use variables, but I strongly doubt that was the intent in this case ;-)

Comment: up-voted for the link to the doc which should be provided in each answer to a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hiddenLayerinput = {
    units: 64, 
    activation: 'relu', 
    input_dim: 5,
}
```